# Why this limit sentence $(a_n{})^{b_n{}}= e^{b_n{} (a_n{}-1)}$(...) only true if $\lim_{n \to \infty}{a_n}=1$

Tags: calculus, limits

Why is it true that the limit of those expressions are equal
$$
(a_n{})^{b_n{}}= e^{b_n{} (a_n{}-1)}
$$
Only if the limit of a[n] is 1.

If the explanation to this equation is 
$$
(1+a_n{}-1)^{b_n{}} = ((1+(a_n{}-1))^{1/a_n{}-1})^{b_n*(a_n-1)}
$$
And because the limit of
$$
(1+(a_n{}-1))^{1/a_n{}-1}  = e
$$
Then the whole expression equals to 
$$
e^{b_n*(a_n-1)}
$$
I thought maybe the limit of a[n] - 1 needs to be infinity but if the limit of a[n] is 1 it doesn't necessarily mean the limit of a[n] - 1 is infinity because it depends if the limit of a[n] is 1+ or 1-.

Comment: Is this intended to hold for arbitrary sequences $(a_n)$, $(b_n)$? I answered as if that were the case.

Comment: Yes although I saw that it could be used for functions as well when it doesn't only look at the limit at infinity but at the limit in any number.

Comment: My answer holds for that as well, I think, although I'd need you to state the desired result precisely before I could check.

Answer (score 1):

By letting $b_n = 1$ for all $n$, we obtain $$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} e^{a_n - 1}$$

Writing $a$ for the limit, we have $$a = e^{a-1}$$

The only solution to this is $a=1$. You can see this by differentiating the function $f(a) = e^{a-1} - a$, for example: the function is locally extremized at $a=1$, where it happens to attain the value $0$. Examining the derivative, we see that $f$ is strictly decreasing on $a < 1$ and strictly increasing on $a > 1$, so that must be a minimum and indeed must be the only minimum.